# Python Fabric: How to retrieve a filelist of a dir

Tags: python, file, fabric, dir, filelist

I'm building a remote server admin tool using the python-fabric library and am looking for a good way of retrieving a filelist for a directory on the remote server. Currently I'm using run("ls dir") and am manually splitting the return string, which seems horrendous and very much architecture dependent. fabric.contrib.files doesn't seem to contain anything of use..

Suggestions much appreciated.

Cheers,
R

Comment: The "official" answer according to the fabric maintainer is to see fabric as a pass-through for shell commands. Hence, the current way of doing this is by using the "ls" command. Furthermore, "ls -l" should output a file per line, making processing easier..

Comment: First you ask how to get a remote list of files - and by specifying Fabric you are also specifying SSH, which implicitly means a UNIX shell.  It's wrong to then comment elsewhere that the best answer (jathanism) is environmentally dependent. 

If you have an OS X, Linux, or even a WINDOWS box that runs SSH -- then 'ls -l' will work.

Strictly speaking, ls -l is not a function of the architecture (as you suggest), and it's not even a function of the OS. ls is a builtin to sh-compatible shells, which exist on all platforms including Windows. Certainly on any SSH shell.

Answer (score 17):

What's wrong with this?

```
output = run('ls /path/to/files')
files = output.split()
print files
```

Check the [documentation on `run()`](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/api/core/operations.html#fabric.operations.run) for more tricks.

Comment: its wrong in that the output of "ls" is completely dependent on the environment you are using, hence it is not architecture independent which you want to be.

Comment: How many system types are you trying to support? It might be better to go with a conditional handling of the output. There is also `ls -1` (list one file per line) which SHOULD behave the same on all POSIX-based systems.

Comment: I've used this trick before, but after reading [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) I'm not sure it's the best solution.

Comment: It's important to understand jpihl's link, but note that the cautionary tale against parsing 'ls' is a LOCAL code scenario. And if you can avoid parsing ls, please do.

But if you need to do a REMOTE ls, then you have no alternative except to parse ls OR you can scp over a more secure file and run that file. But lots of us running Fabric do not have the luxury of moving scripts onto a box just before running those scripts. And doing that wouldn't be solving the problem in Fabric, as the original question requests.

Answer (score 8):

I think the best way is to write a BASH (others shells behave similar) oneliner. To retrieve list of files in a directory.

```
for i in *; do echo $i; done
```

So the complete solution that returns absolute paths:

```
from fabric.api import env, run, cd

env.hosts = ["localhost"]
def list_dir(dir_=None):
    """returns a list of files in a directory (dir_) as absolute paths"""
    dir_ = dir_ or env.cwd
    string_ = run("for i in %s*; do echo $i; done" % dir_)
    files = string_.replace("\r","").split("\n")
    print files
    return files

def your_function():
    """docstring"""
    with cd("/home/"):
        list_dir()
```